# qt 4.7 or 4.8 on RHEL 6.4

Tags: linux, redhat, maptiler

I am a Linux newbie.
I am trying to install the MapTiler product on Redhat 6.4, but the MapTiler RPM has been made for Redhat 7 with dependencies to the Redhat 7 GUI libraries. I will not use the MapTiler GUI, but only use it through the command line. The dependencies are therefore hopefully not strictly necessary.

The install is tried executed as:

```
sudo yum install maptiler-0.5.5-pro-linux.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

but it the output is:

```
Error: Package: maptiler-pro-0.5.5.1-1.x86_64 (/maptiler-0.5.5-pro-linux.el7.x86_64)
       Requires: qt4 >= 4.7
       Installed: 1:qt-4.6.2-25.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201301301459.x86_64/6.4)
           qt4 = 4.6.2-25.el6
       Available: 1:qt-4.6.2-16.el6.i686 (rhel-x86_64-server-6-prod)
           qt4 = 4.6.2-16.el6
       Available: 1:qt-4.6.2-17.el6.i686 (rhel-x86_64-server-6-prod)
           qt4 = 4.6.2-17.el6
       Available: 1:qt-4.6.2-17.el6_1.1.i686 (rhel-x86_64-server-6-prod)
           qt4 = 4.6.2-17.el6_1.1
       Available: 1:qt-4.6.2-19.el6.i686 (rhel-x86_64-server-6-prod)
           qt4 = 4.6.2-19.el6
       Available: 1:qt-4.6.2-20.el6.i686 (rhel-x86_64-server-6-prod)
           qt4 = 4.6.2-20.el6
       Available: 1:qt-4.6.2-24.el6.i686 (rhel-x86_64-server-6-prod)
           qt4 = 4.6.2-24.el6
       Available: 1:qt-4.6.2-26.el6_4.i686 (rhel-x86_64-server-6-prod)
           qt4 = 4.6.2-26.el6_4
       Available: 1:qt-4.6.2-28.el6_5.i686 (rhel-x86_64-server-6-prod)
           qt4 = 4.6.2-28.el6_5
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Any clue of what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MapTiler Pro are available the "headless" binaries as well - both .rpm and .deb. RedHat 6x is supported with these directly.

If you use these all the dependencies of your system are going to be met automatically - you will just need to install EPEL6 in your RedHat 6.4 and install the maptiler rpm.

For adding EPEL6 see tutorial: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_can_I_install_the_packages_from_the_EPEL_software_repository.3F

Please contact info@klokantech.com and request the binary for headless el6 linux. This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have by now provided me with the correct RHEL 6 binaries. Thank you.

I must however also state, that I ended up posting this question on a Sunday, because when asked if Maptiler 7.5 binaries for RHEL 7 would work on RHEL 6, your support saw no problems and encouraged me to try it out. Stuck with no support on a Sunday I ended on StackOverflow.

Your answer above is however correct and thus rewarded as such.